# Relating the class number of a field, and of its normal closure

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, class-field-theory, ideal-class-group

Suppose I take a number field $ K $, not necessarily Galois, with class number $ h_k $ (over $ \mathbb{Q} $).  Write $ \overline{K} $ for the normal closure of $ K $.  What, if anything, can be said about the relation between $ h_K $ and $ h_{\overline{K}} $?  A question dealing with one particular case of interest is presented at the end.

In general I know there is no real relationship between the class number of a field $ E $, and of an extension $ F \supset E $.  Probably the best example of this is $ \mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d}) $, with $ d $ squarefree.  We have that $ h_{\mathbb{Q}} = 1 $, but $ h_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})} \to \infty $ as $ d \to \infty $.  In particular there can be no upper bound on $ h_F $ as a function of only $ h_E $ and $ [F\colon E] $.

However, from class field theory we do get the following observation.  Let $ H(E) $ denote the Hilbert class field of $ E $.  Then the fields $ E \subset F $ fit into the following diagram.
\begin{array}{cc}
& H(F) & \\ 
\quad \huge\diagup & {\huge|} h_{F} \\
H(E) & F \\
{\huge|} h_E & {\huge\diagup} [F\colon E] \\
E
\end{array}
We conclude that $ h_E \mid h_F [F \colon E] $.  But of course, in the previous case this tell us the trivial result that $ 1 \mid h_F [F \colon E] $.  Can anything more precise be said in the case $ K \subset \overline{K} $?

Initially, I wondered/hoped if there was some bound like $ h_{\overline{K}} \mid [\overline{K}\colon K] h_k^{[\overline{K} \colon K]} $, but after some numerical experimentations with Magma, I find this doesn't hold.  For example with $ K = \mathbb{Q}(\theta) $, where $ \theta $ is a root of $ 2 + 7x + 2x^2 + 8x^3 $, we get that $ h_K = 2 $ and $ h_{\overline{K}} = 88 $.  Somehow a factor of 11 suddenly appears.  But maybe this has to do with the fact that the discriminant $ \Delta_{\overline{K}} $ contains a factor of 11?

This open-ended question is motivated by a specific observation which occurred when I looked at the the pure cubic fields $ K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{n}) $.  Here the situation seems more 'rigid'.  In this case $ \overline{K} = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{n}, \sqrt{-3}) $, and in all cube-free cases from $ n = 1, \ldots, 1000 $, I seem to find that $ h_{\overline{K}} \mid h_K^2 $.  But moreover $$ h_K^2 / h_{\overline{K}} \in \{ 1, 3 \} \, . $$

> **Question:** Is this true generally for $ K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{n}) $ that $ h_{\overline{K}} \mid h_K^2 $?  Even more, do we have $ h_K^2 / h_{\overline{K}} \in \{ 1, 3 \} $.  If so, how can this be proven?  Is this a shadow of some more general result?
>
> **Extra:** If it is true that for $ K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{n}) $, we have $ h_K^2 / h_{\overline{K}} \in \{ 1, 3 \} $.  Is there anything about $ n $, or $ K $, which lets us predict whether the case $ h_K^2 / h_{\overline{K}} = 1 $  occurs, or the case $ h_K^2 / h_{\overline{K}} = 3 $?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your guess is not far from the truth: in the case of an $S_3$-extension, the class number of the normal closure is, up to a bounded factor involving a unit index, the product of the class numbers of the subfields over which the normal closure is cyclic. Since the quadratic subfield has class number $1$ in the pure cubic case, your guess is true here. In your other example, the additional factor $11$ must come from the class number of the quadratic subfield ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{{\rm disc}(K)})$ of the normal closure. Similar remarks apply in the general case.  For details see the literature; looking for "class number formulas" should give you enough papers to start with.

Comment: Knowing better what to search lead me to the paper "On Units and Class Numbers of Pure Cubic Fields", by Nils Reich. This paper exactly answers the specific question I asked. Do you have any specific references for the general case?